# Magento 2: Hiding a custom tab in backend

Tags: magento-2.1

I have added a custom tab in Order view in backend. I need to hide the tab conditionally.

I have tried setting `canShowTab()` and `isHidden()` in by Module's Tabs Block to `false` and `true` respectively. But the tab still shows.

**How can I hide this custom tab from my block ?**

PS: I have tried clearing the cache, and have also done an upgrade.

```
namespace Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab;


class Paymentdetails extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
{
    /**
     * Template
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'order/view/tab/paymentdetails.phtml';


    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve order model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->coreRegistry->registry('current_order');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Custom tab');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Custom tab');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return false;
        // return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return true;
        // return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get Tab Class
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabClass()
    {
        return 'ajax only';
    }

    /**
     * Get Class
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getClass()
    {
        return $this->getTabClass();
    }

    /**
     * Get Tab Url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('paymentdetails/*/paymentdetails', ['_current' => true]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you try to remove `var/generation` folder?

Comment: Yes I have. Also flushed cache and upgraded.